# How to create full time string from hours and minutes in Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have time strings having only hours and minutes, for example '19:39', '21:37', '14:10'.

I'd like to put such a string in a moment.js function like `format()` and get a string with seconds: '19:39:00', '21:37:00', etc. The seconds value will be always '00'. I tried with the `format` function but it returns `Invalid date` all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const str = "19:39";
//parse string to moment using format string to dictate what the string constains
const m = moment(str, "H:mm");
//output moment in new format
console.log(m.format("H:m:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Here's a reference to the [string format options](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: I changed the format a bit ```moment(str, 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm:ss')``` but generally it is what I was trying to achieve, thanks :).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's no need to use `moment` if you just need to get a string

```
`${'19:39'}:00`
```

will be enough, right?

Btw, `moment('19:39', 'H:mm').format('H:m:ss')` will do the job.

Comment: I used such a solution before but I don't want to rely purely on strings.